# How can I install Adobe AIR?

Tags: software-installation, adobe-air

I am a heavy user of certain applications that are built on AIR.

It appears that AIR has discontinued support for Linux. Even the older versions in the Adobe AIR Archives seem to support only 32 bit Linux distributions and I am on 64 bit currently.

Is there even a slight possibility that I could run AIR in these conditions? If so, can you please tell me where can I get a detailed step by step installation for this?

Comment: Note that Adobe have ended support for AIR on Linux. Adobe is also moving away from legacy technologies such as Flash and AIR into HTML5 which is the future.

Comment: I installed adobe air from .deb file in oneric

Answer (score 229, accepted):

1. Download Latest Version Air 2.6.0 For Linux to your Desktop:

   - http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin - 15.4Mb or find runtime files in [Archived Adobe AIR SDK versions](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html)

     2. Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal
     3. `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`  - (32bit rubbish if you want to run this in x64 Ubuntu; if you have trouble, see ["Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable" - Solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/282194))
     4. `cd Desktop` (change dir. to Desktop dir.)
     5. `chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin` (change mode - execute permission yes)
     6. `./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`
        (after you accept the Adobe Air license, it will prompt you for your password; it needs root access in order to install)

#### Maybe you'll get an error after the last command?

> Sorry, an error has occurred. Adobe AIR could not be installed. Install either Gnome Keyring or KDE KWallet before installing Adobe AIR.

This can be fixed:

- In a terminal (default shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+T), type:

  ```
  locate libgnome-keyring.so
  ```
- This is my result (yours might be different):

  ```
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
  ```
- As suggested below by @jmendeth, the easiest way to tell the installer where to find these files is to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

  - For 32-bit Ubuntu (tested on 12.04):

    ```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
    ```
  - For 64-bit Ubuntu, the command line would probably be:

    ```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
    ```

If the LD_LIBRARY_PATH trick doesn't work, you can try this:

- Create a symbolic link to your location strings that you found with the previous commands:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
  ```
- Use following commands for 32-bit systems:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
  ```
- Then repeat step 4 & 6 (skip 5, as the permission to execute the file hasn't changed).
- Remove symbolic links after installation of Adobe AIR 2.6.0:

  ```
  sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
  sudo rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
  ```

Reference:

- Archived Adobe AIR SDK versions - https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html
- Install 32-bit Adobe AIR for desktop Linux - https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/install-32-bit-air-linux.html
- Install Adobe AIR 2 for 64-bit Linux systems - https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/install-air-2-64-bit.html
- www.clarifylinux.org/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-tweak-and-hack-round-up.html

Comment: Great! It's installed. Now if I only can install an AIR package...

Comment: Will "installing 32bit crap" in x64 negatively impact performance at all?

Comment: Doesn't AIR respect `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Just askin'

Comment: I created an account just to upvote this +1

Comment: I cannot possibly +1 you enough.

Comment: Incredible answer! It was extremely clear and one of the best answers I've seen on this site. I can now install AIR packages at ease.

Comment: i had to use sudo before `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin` command, as I was asked for password for `root` user, which is nonsense for Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you make this a community wiki?

Comment: It's not working for me on Xubuntu 13.10.

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. However the following packages replace it:
  lib32asound2 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin 
/tmp/air.kmEATV/setup: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @SlavaFominII You need to install i386 libraries. Try `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386`. I got the 2 problems like you but solved installing it.

Comment: For Xenial, I needed to install: `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3:i386`

Answer (score 43):

### Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04, 15.04 and 15.10 (64 bit)

1. Install i386 libraries, that are required for successful installation and running of Adobe Air and air applications.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxt6:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
   ```
2. Install `libgnome-keyring0:i386` package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring0:i386
   ```
3. Create symlinks to gnome-keyring so Adobe Air could see it.

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0

   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
   ```
4. Download Adobe Air installer from [here](http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin).
5. Give execute permission and then run that .bin file.

   ```
   sudo chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
   sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
   ```

[Source](http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/installing-adobe-air-and-elance-tracker-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-64-bit)

#### Note for Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)

For Ubuntu 16.04 and greater, install the package `libnss-mdns:i386` instead of the package `lib32nss-mdns`. This will solve the problem of "Package not found error" related to that package.

Comment: So, how do I uninstall Adobe Air?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10. Anyone else who need this for e-Deklaracje app ?

Comment: Hi all. Pls feel free to update my answer if it works for recent versions.

Comment: 16.04, got an error that `lib32nss-mdns` was missing. When installer opened got `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"`. Seems to have installed correctly. But the app I needed AIR for needs a more recent version :/

Comment: @raphael Install `libnss-mdns:i386` package instead.

Answer (score 19):

Alternately, you can install a prebuilt .deb

There is air 2.6 (last supported Linux one) available [here](http://update.devolo.com/linux/apt/pool/main/a/adobeair/) for both architectures (Both use 32 bit underneath but at least it works). Thanks to [prusswan](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11709088&postcount=4) for pointing it out.

Make sure you have 32 bit libs it'll need:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I downloaded the AMD64 one (adobeair_2.6.0.19170_amd64.deb) and installed on my computer (am64 with Precise Pangolin 12.04)

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i adobeair_2.6.0.19170_amd64.deb
```

Then I installed the application that needed Adobe Air in the first place and it worked.

**Update for Ubuntu 13:10+**,

Trying this technique, i get "Package ia32-libs-gtk is not installed"

I looked up [the package](http://packages.debian.org/jessie/ia32-libs-gtk-i386) and tried installing those dependencies and other related packages I can think of directly:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines:i386 libart-2.0-2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libgail-common:i386 libgconf2-4:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 liblua5.1-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libthai0:i386 libbonobo2-0:i386 libglade2-0:i386 libgnomecanvas2-0:i386 libidl0:i386 liborbit2:i386 libwmf0.2-7:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

But that didn't work for either the deb or [original binary](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html#main_Adobe_AIR_2_6_runtime_downloads).

Comment: I have searched the internet high and low and your install link is the only one that worked. 

**Note to future visitors:** if you're using the AdobeAIRInstaller.bin and getting a `Gtk WARNING **: cannot open display:` error, try this!

Comment: this is much easier than http://jeffhendricks.net/?p=68

Comment: Dug a little deeper than nora and found the answer regarding the "cannot open display" issue. Problem is you can't have the root user connect to the X display in Ubuntu (with default settings), but we need to run our installer as root (fail-design). First install sux (switchuser with X credentials). Allow the root user to connect to X display. Get current display settings. Then use sux to switch to root user. Run installer with display settings.

1. `sudo apt-get install sux`
2. `/usr/bin/xhost +`
3. `echo $DISPLAY` (use this in step 5)
4. `sudo sux -`
5. `DISPLAY=:0.0 ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`

Answer (score 14):

### Ubuntu 14.04 - *32 and 64 bit* - easy .deb install

Because of the way that multiarch works, you can can now simply install the i386 .deb file on newer 64bit Ubuntu and it will automatically install the right dependencies. (Also the 64 bit .deb is just the 32bit repackaged with a dependency on ia32-libs)

1. Download the 32 bit(yes even for your 64 bit Ubuntu) deb: http://update.devolo.com/linux/apt/pool/main/a/adobeair/adobeair_2.6.0.19170-devolo1_i386.deb (Thanks to yuvilio's answer) <sub>*The 64 bit package on the same site is a repackaged version of the 32 bit, you will have problems if you use the 64 bit package instead, use the 32 bit package for both 32 and 64 bit systems Ubuntu 13.10+.*</sub>
2. Open in software center, click **Install**

   [image]
   <sub>Ignore the warning about package quality</sub>

---

Alternatively if you have a Steam game that requires Air, simply install and run that game and it will install Air on the first run of the game.

Example games that use Air:

- Defenders Quest
- Anodyne (gets confused if you already have Air installed, run `sudo apt-get remove adobeair` and try the game installer again since it comes with Air)

I found these during a [Weekly Humble Sale](https://www.humblebundle.com/weekly) to support some open source projects.

Comment: I'm running Kali Linux and wanted to install the `devolo-dlan-cockpit` package, which requires `adobeair`. For me this solution worked perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Get some Air
Next download the Adobe Air .bin file ([direct link here](http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/latest/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin)).

Step 2: Installation

Open a terminal (applications > Accessories > Terminal) and navigate to your Downloads folder (or the folder in which you saved the .bin file).

```
* cd Download/
```

We need to let the .bin file have permissions to install so enter the following command carefully: -

```
* chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Now lets install it:

```
* ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Installation should zip though and, if everything goes okay, a new menu entry will appear in ‘Applications > Accessories’ titled ‘Adobe Air Application Installer’.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 13.10 x64

Answer (score 4):

...finally after some trouble and after many searches on this forum, google and others pages have managed to do it.
First I want to thank the community that gave me more ambition to do it, than make me quit to install AdobeAir.

Whole problem was the package **ia32-libs**(*The ia32-libs package was a hack to get 32-bit packages installed on a 64-bit installation. Since Ubuntu version 11.10 (Oneiric), Multi Arch has been added. One of the objectives for it is removing the ia32-libs package*)... package that Canonical has decided to end support for it.

All I had to do to install **ia32-libs** package was to add this  repo:

**1**-  ''*deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiversepackage source*''

I followed the steps from this quick and easy tutorial:

*http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-13-10*

**2**- then this page that leads me to this nice **steps to install Adobe Air For 64-bit Systems**

*www.thepowerbase.com/2013/06/how-to-install-adobe-air-in-ubuntu-13-04/*

-----------------***documentation that I used:***---------------

```
www.askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air
helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html
www.wiki.phoenixviewer.com/ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-13-10
www.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181649
www.askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-    unsupported-release
```

**P.S.** ---as noted by Alvar, **Adobe Air for Linux** is no longer supported---

Comment: Check out this link.  It worked well.  http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/installing-adobe-air-and-elance-tracker-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-64-bit

Comment: @MichaelMikowski Your link helped me. The above links did not have a solution of manual coping library which could not be installed. After that, I got AdobeAir installed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, many years late "Adobe AIR for Linux is no longer supported." following what adobe page says. Using the "AIR archive" is possible to get unsupported versions, the 2.6.0 version is the most recent available. If you need to install a program that require a newer version of it, you might go to Virtual box with a Windows guest.

The recommend steps for Ubuntu 16.10:

for 32bit machine

```
wget -O adobe-air_i386.deb http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobeair_2.6.0.2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f && rm adobe-air_i386.deb
```

for 64bit machine

```
wget -O adobe-air_amd64.deb http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobeair_2.6.0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f && rm adobe-air_amd64.deb
```

The recommend steps for Ubuntu 16.04/14.04/12.04/Linux Mint 18/17/13 (both extracted from [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html)):

```
wget -O adobe-air.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobe-air.sh
chmod +x adobe-air.sh;sudo ./adobe-air.sh
```

Comment: source still available, and method still works. Awesome!

Comment: the full source: https://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: i just don't agree with recommending `dpkg -i file.deb && apt-get install -f` to install a deb-package... rather use `apt install ./file.deb` or `gdebi file.deb`! **--** source: https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/354350

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. The only way of installing Adobe Air that worked for me was to follow the first part of these [instructions for installing Balsamiq on Ubuntu](http://anishdeena.tumblr.com/post/79543943215/installing-balsamiq-on-ubuntu), which is what I was trying to do in the first place.

A brief summary of those instructions:
- Download [this Adobe Air installer](http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/latest/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin)
- Installing the 32-bit libgtk package (but I skipped this step; it didn't work for me, and didn't seem necessary)
- Making symbolic links to two libgnome-keyring files
- Making the Adobe Air installer executable and running it with sudo

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this worked for me:

```
wget -O adobe-air_i386.deb http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobeair_2.6.0.2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_i386.deb
```

Here it will throw an error saying that the package have unmet dependencies.

Run this and it should install what's needed:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

#### If that doesn't work:

I've tried a few things before as well, and I'm not sure if that's necessary for it to work. I've had run: `sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3:i386 libxaw7:i386`

As a general tip, see if some error pops up when running `sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_i386.deb` and try to solve it by installing the necessary packages.