# How to install an .air file?

Tags: installation, adobe-air

I have downloaded conqu from [here](http://conqu.com/download) and the downloaded file is .air i don't know what this extension is and is it executable or not, so how to install it on Ubuntu 11.10 ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run Conqu on Linux, you need Adobe AIR. If you already have it, then you simply double click on Conqu's downloaded file. Otherwise, install AIR first:

- [How can I install Adobe AIR?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air)

After the installer runs successfully, [download and install Conqu](http://conqu.com/help/kb/desktop-help/how-to-install-conqu-on-linux).

Comment: tks @jorge Castro for the edit