# Adobe Air workaround for Pandora not working

Tags: password, root, authentication, adobe-air, pandora

I was trying this symbolic link approach because of the problem described here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/120221/70462

After I made the symlink, the installation proceeded further than before, but it eventually asked for my password (in an extra small x-term window within the AIR installation window). When I typed in my password, it told me there was an authentication failure. I tried about 8 times total (on 3 separate install attempts), but even when I was certain I was typing my password correctly, it would tell me there was an authentication error.

Specifically the text in the x-term window was:

```
TITLEBAR: xdg-su: /tmp/air.x0rSdF/setup
TERM:  This application requires administrative rights to run
Please enter root Password:
su: Authentication failure
Please enter root Password:
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should only be happening if you did not run the Adobe AIR Installer (`AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`) as `root` using `sudo`.

Did you run

```
sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

as in [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/120221/22949) (step 6)?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that's how I did that.  I wanted to do it again before posting to that effect, but I was trying to do it late at night and it wasn't working.  I wanted to start the process over and make sure I had the symbolic links gone from the previous time (the commands sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0).  While trying to make sure I did that, I think I got a little too thorough and deleted the (in term) red files with that name in /usr/lib.  Now when I do a locate for libgnome-keyring.so.0, it comes up empty.  What sould I do?

Comment: @Rick If you accidentally delete a file provided by an Ubuntu package, reinstalling the package is usually the best approach to fixing this. As [this search reveals](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgnome-keyring.so.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any), these files are provided by `libgnome-keyring0`, so run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgnome-keyring0` and you should get [`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0` and `libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libgnome-keyring0/filelist) back.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that.  I hadn't known how to do that.  I guess I would have expected reinstallation to be an option in the Ubuntu Software Center.  Is it?

Comment: This solved my problems of my drives missing.  Now I guess I go back to trying the AIR install from scratch and see if that works.

Comment: @Rick I don't think you can do that in the Software Center. Of course, you can uninstall a package and then install it again in two separate steps, but that's less advisable because there's potentially more opportunity for something to go wrong in between. The Synaptic Package Manager (provided by the package `synaptic`, which you can install via the command-line or in the Software Center) does provide this advanced functionality.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have resolved the AdobeAIR problem as well.  I'm guessing I just forgot to sudo last time.  Thank you for pointing that out so gently.   One curious point though.  This time when I tried to use "locate libgnome-keyring.so.0" it returned nothing.  Last time, it showed me the path in /usr...  This time I knew what it was from before so I just used it.  But I'm not sure why locate no longer works for me (perhaps has something to do with me reinstalling the libgnome-keyring stuff after I accidentally removed the wrong ones?  I would click "Answered" but I'm not sure howt.

Comment: If you have system files (including files from installed packages) that locate isn't finding, run `sudo updatedb` (see [`man updatedb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/updatedb.8.html) and [`man locate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mlocate.1.html) for details).

Answer (score -1):

Go to your adobe air installation location via the **terminal** (for me it's /opt/Adobe AIR/Versions/1.0). In here you'll find the "Adobe AIR Application Installer". Run this "Adobe AIR Application Installer" with sudo (sudo ./Adobe\ AIR\ Application\ Installer). Then you'll be given a window to select your ".air" file. Just select your file and click ok. Then there won't be any password prompt anymore. Worked for me. Hope it'll do good to you too. Good luck :)

Comment: The above answer gives the exact same suggestion, but in more detail.

Comment: oh, it speaks about the .bin file right??? as per my knowledge it'll install adobe air, what I said was after the above step, that means after (sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin) adobe air will be installed and then go to the installation directory and run adobe air application installer with sudo permision...

Comment: pathetic... wonder if the down voter had at least bothered to check whether this answer works at all...