# How to install Showcase 5

Tags: installation, package-management, adobe

just trying to install Showcase 5 for ubuntu. I believe it is a adobe air package but I can't find it. thanks for the help

Comment: Take a look at [How can I install Adobe AIR?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air) Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, install in ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 ia32-libs libjpeg62:i386
```

Then in terminal :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

Finally download v2.6, (not the last version, but adobe decided to stop devel for linux...)

http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin

```
sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```