# "Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable" - Solution

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, dependencies, multiarch, architecture

I noticed this on 12.10 trying to get the Android SDK working. For 64 bit versions, it is required to install:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

However, under 64bit 12.10, I got the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
```

And

```
> apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ia32-libs-multiarch' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/1016294) comment #27,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Then the 32 bit libraries install fine (for me anyway!). Hope this helps somebody !

Comment: This solution is now obsolete: `Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

Comment: dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture

Comment: sudo apt-file -a i386 update; sudo apt-file update; for f in $(< libs.txt) ; do test -f "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/$f" || test -f "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/$f" || { echo -n "$f: " ; ps=($(apt-file -a i386 -x search "/$f\$" | sed -e 's/\([^:]*\): .*/\1/g')); echo "${ps[@]}" ; } ; done

# Copy and paste desired package names from the output of the above script into the libs variable below.
libs=(foo bar baz) ; sudo apt-get install "${libs[@]/%/:i386}"

Comment: @bancer -- you need to upgrade dpkg: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade dpkg`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer no longer works, as you see by comments. I found a working solution elsewhere:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

[Link is here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364968/installing-skype-in-ubuntu-13-10).

Comment: Still doesn't work for me... maybe it's changed yet again since your answer