# How can I install Adobe Air on 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation

Hy, I used this tutorial and didn't work 
[how-can-i-install-adobe-air](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air)

and also this [how-to-install-adobe-2-6-air-on-ubuntu](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-adobe-2-6-air-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-and-linux-mint-15-olivia/)

if someone could help me with any tips about installing I remain fully grateful.