# How do I install 32-bit libraries when they keep having uninstallable dependencies?

Tags: apt, software-installation, adobe-air

I'm trying to install Adobe Air on Ubuntu 13.10. In this version of Ubuntu, packages like `ia32-libs` and `ia32-libs-multiarch` are no longer available, so I'm trying to install the needed 32-bit libraries on my own. When running `./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin` I got several errors about missing libraries, most of which I managed to install using `sudo apt-get install <library-name>:i386` and the errors went away. I'm having issues fixing the last two missing modules though:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

I tried installing `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386` using apt:

```
overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 : Depends: overlay-scrollbar:i386 but it is not installable
```

Well darn, it depends on a package that can't be installed. How inconvenient. So I tried Googling my way forth to the 32-bit overlay-scrollbar libraries for Saucy, [which I found here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-unity/+archive/daily-build/+build/4908417). First I installed overlay-scrollbar:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i overlay-scrollbar_0.2.16+r359+13.10.20130826-0ubuntu1_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 226507 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace overlay-scrollbar 0.2.16+r359+13.10.20130826-0ubuntu1 (using overlay-scrollbar_0.2.16+r359+13.10.20130826-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement overlay-scrollbar ...
Setting up overlay-scrollbar (0.2.16+r359+13.10.20130826-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 ...
```

Great! It worked. Then I tried installing overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i overlay-scrollbar-gtk2_0.2.16+r359+13.10.20130826-0ubuntu1_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386.
(Reading database ... 226507 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 (from overlay-scrollbar-gtk2_0.2.16+r359+13.10.20130826-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386:
 overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 depends on overlay-scrollbar.

dpkg: error processing overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386
```

So apparently I still need to install overlay-scrollbar:i386, which is not installable by apt and didn't get installed by the installer above. My issues with unity-gtk-module are pretty much identical but with different package names.

I have a couple of very related questions regarding this:

- Why are some very important 32-bit packages not installable using apt? Am I missing a source?
- Why didn't the i386 version of overlay-scrollbar get installed above? Is it because the installer contains both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the library and automatically decided to install just the 64-bit one on my system? Can I force it to install both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Adobe AIR?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air)

Comment: @Mateo: The questions are related, but not duplicates. My question is more about getting around the "uninstallable dependencies" issue rather than how to install Adobe Air.

Comment: Last I tried the 32 bit deb worked with no workarounds on both 32 and 64, if this is something new that is needed to workaround getting air working, these answers need to be in that question. Unless it is a bug - which it seems you have also filed a bug report - this should be closed as a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apt-get download overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends overlay-scrollbar -i overlay-scrollbar-gtk2*.deb
```

Simple.

This will work, if you've already installed package for your architecture. If not, you will get errors, while trying to use dpkg/apt-get next time. To fix them, run:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Find `Package: [package name, overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 in this case]`, and remove ignored dependencies from `Depends:` (overlay-scrollbar in this case).

If you use gedit, **make sure you've disabled automatic backups** in Edit > Preferences > Editor before saving. Notice that gedit has seperate preferences for each user, and you're running it as root.

Comment: On updated 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.4 I had to do this instead: `apt-get download overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386` `;` `sudo dpkg --force-depends -i overlay-scrollbar-gtk2_*_i386.deb`.

Answer (score 4):

The overlay-scrollbar package does not come in i386 or amd64 flavors; it comes as an "all" flavor, which installs on all archs.

It appears to be missing the Multi-Arch: allowed header so it won't satisfy an i386 package depending on it.  You should file a bug report asking that the missing header be added.

Comment: In the meantime, is there any way to fool overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:i386 to accepting overlay-scrollbar:all? Perhaps a clever symlink somewhere? I don't see any other way of getting AIR to work on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1262022)