# GTK-Message and warnings in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: themes, 14.04, gtk

Since updating to Ubuntu 14.04 I've started getting this error message when running GNUcash. GNUcash says it has nothing to do with them and they suggested asking Ubuntu for help.

So can anyone help with this message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(npviewer.bin:18843): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

There is more of it, but it just repeats the same lines over and over again.

I've also found these error messages which might help someone find me a cure!

```
peter@ubuntu:~$ strace gedit 2>&1 | grep can

access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.la", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so", F_OK) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23112, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 10
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-gtk3.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 10
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gedit/libcanberra.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 10
writev(8, [{"\22\0\17\0\205\0@\4p\1\0\0\33\1\0\0\10\0\0\0!\0\0\0/com/can"..., 176}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 176
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-0.30/libcanberra-pulse.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra-0.30/libcanberra-pulse.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 15
peter@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Did you remove some packages from your system? What theme are you using?

Comment: I didn't remove anything I just an upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. No errors reported during the update.

Comment: I'm using unity - and Ambiance theme with Icons from Faenza

Comment: GEdit is using GTK+ 3.x, while GNUCash is using GTK+ 2.x, so running strace on gedit to debug your issue with gnucash, is a bit odd, and not really going to help you at all.

Comment: Is this still an issue @Peter?

Comment: Hi Oli, I now only have 2 error messages - both about the overlay-scrollbar-gkt2 and unity-gtk2-modules. I've managed to get the other murrine warnings to disappear. I think it's because I need to install the 32bit versions of the overlay-scrollbar-gkt2 and unity-gtk2-module - but when I try I get errors. This isn't stopping anything working so I think I'll just ignore it! Unless you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The *Message* lines mean you are missing the `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` and `unity-gtk2-module` packages.

The *WARNING* is because you are apparently missing the `gtk2-engines-murrine` package.

Comment: I have both of these packages installed. I've checked and re-installed both - but error messages are still there

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your install. Those messages do not happen for me.

Comment: I had thought that - as I did an upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 - I think I'll have to do a clean install as I have other problems too. Thankfully I have a separate Home partition so it should be easy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've now been able to reduce the number of GTK errors by sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386

Comment: I'm now left with just these errors: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

Comment: So you are trying to use gnucash:i386 on a 64-bit system? Install the :i386 versions of the packages in my answer then, or better yet, install the 64-bit gnucash.

Comment: i didn't know there was a 64 bit version of GNUcash

Comment: How did you install it exactly? If you open up software center on 64-bit ubuntu, search for "gnucash" and install it, you will get the correct version of gnucash.

Comment: I installed it via Getdeb because they have the newest releases which the software centre usually doesn't

Comment: I've checked and I think I have the 64 bit version installed because I've found the i386 version which isn't installed so by a process of illumination I think I have the 64 bit version installed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/392097/how-do-i-install-32-bit-libraries-when-they-keep-having-uninstallable-dependenci which explain how to resolve it.  However if I understand https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1134202 correctly, this is only "noise", and not actually causing any real issue?