# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module" Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gtk, adobe-reader

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 recently on my computer. After I followed [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-1404/) link to install Adobe pdf reader, ever time I use xdg-open to open a pdf file, there are tons of message showing on my screen:

> (acroread: 31045): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

There are also two lines of messages:

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
>
> Gtk-Message: Failed t0 load module "unity-gtk-module"

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208431/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module) link and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed) link. And I tried the bash command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/
```

following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061142) link. None of them work.
The pdf files cold be opened, but these tons of warnings are annoying. could anyone tell me how to eliminate these messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the "murrine" messages, the following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

The other two messages seem more complicated to remove manually, and at least the first one is due to a bug - see [How do I install 32-bit libraries when they keep having uninstallable dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392097/how-do-i-install-32-bit-libraries-when-they-keep-having-uninstallable-dependenci) and bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/overlay-scrollbar/+bug/1134202 .