# Adobe AIR install problem, Ubuntu x64 14.04

Tags: 14.04, adobe-air

Haven't seen this kind of error on askubuntu yet.

Did everything as it says here:
[How can I install Adobe AIR?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87447/how-can-i-install-adobe-air)

After `sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`
shows this image:
dropbox.com/s/wg6cv03h5n1tqgr/adobe_air.png

Meanwhile terminal shows a bunch of such messages:

```
(setup:2579): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

Nothing is installed. Those murrine - it showed another code before ( another than setup:2579) - I googled it, installed something, it showed another code - I googled it, installed something, etc. Doesn't seem to affect installation anyhow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course, after one day of googling, after I posted question - the answer has been found.

Here: http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/installing-adobe-air-and-elance-tracker-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-64-bit I've found another set of "before installing adobe air, install these libs" and it worked - unlike tons of those before.

Here it is.

```
sudo apt-get install libxt6:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

And you have to create a symbolic link to your gnome keyring:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

#### Note for Ubuntu 16.04 +

Instead of the package `libnss32-mdns`, install `libnss-mdns:i386` package. That'll solve the problem of package not found error.

Comment: getting this error 'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32nss-mdns' what should I do?

Comment: @Abomm install `libnss-mdns:i386` package instead

Answer (score 6):

Here is the one that works for me: http://stdout.in/en/post/how_to_install_elance_tracker_on_latest_Ubuntu

Taken from the web page:

> Here is one quick script. Save it as install_adobe_air.sh
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
> cd /tmp
> apt-get download libgnome-keyring0:i386
> dpkg-deb -R libgnome-keyring0_3.8.0-2_i386.deb gnome-keyring
> cp gnome-keyring/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
> ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0
> ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
> ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
> wget http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
> chmod a+x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
> ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
> rm ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
> rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
> rm /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
> ```
>
> Make it executable `sudo chmod a+x install_adobe_air.sh`
>   And run `sudo ./install_adobe_air.sh` (during running Abode Air wizard will appear, you should go through it).

Comment: I suggest to add ```apt-get remove adobeair``` as first line in your script. I had to do a complete air runtime uninstall (apt-get remove adobeair) before being able to install scratch 2.x: You script was ok but air application install crashed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo wget -O adobe-air.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobe-air.sh
```

and next

```
sudo chmod +x adobe-air.sh;sudo ./adobe-air.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Just installed Adobe Air on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 with two clicks:

1. Download Debian package from http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/adobeair.deb
2. Install it (e.g. just be double-clicking in your file browser from your download folder)

Ignore warnings that the package is of low quality, etc. - Adobe apparently doesn't care much about this Linux port, so one needs to take what one can get ...

Works fine (needed it for playing Defender's quest: http://steamcommunity.com/app/218410/).