# How can I install ICQ on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, instant-messaging

A lot of people are coming back to ICQ because it was updated and now can compete with WhatsApp.

I'm trying to install the newest ICQ on Ubuntu but I having trouble with that. I access the following adress: http://www.icq.com/download/linux/en ,so I try to click on "Download ICQ" button, however anything happens.

[image]

I didn't found any other link to download ICQ in the official website. Someone can help me?

### Edit to Louis Matthijssen answer:

Well, I follow what you said. I downloaded Chromium and go to [ICQ For Linux download page](http://www.icq.com/download/linux/en). The installation almost works, the page tells me to download and install Adobe Air, I clicked in "Yes" and wait while the Adobe Air was installed. After that I receive the following error:

[image]

Comment: it is a beta version right and it might be risky to use beta versions

Comment: I don't care, I like to live dangerously.

Comment: link is broken i tried it

Comment: @FernandoPaladini then why use Linux and not Windows? :-D

Comment: Take it easy, I'm not so hard yet

Comment: lol. this seeems to suggest you need empathy: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/account-plugin-icq

Comment: But Empathy is ugly, I really want use ICQ :(

Comment: how about get WINE and use ICQ for windows ?

Comment: How about avoid WINE and use WebICQ?

Comment: How about avoid Wine, WebICQ, Empathy and use ICQ For Linux?

Comment: There is a web version, I guess it will work on any platform using an internet browser.

Answer (score 1):

I have got it working in Firefox too:

1. Open a terminal
2. Download the latest Adobe AIR:

   ```
   wget http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
   ```
3. Set the executable bit:

   ```
   chmod +x AdobeAirInstaller.bin
   ```
4. Install Adobe AIR:

   - For 32-bit:

     ```
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
     ```
   - For 64-bit:

     ```
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
     ```

   More information about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/120221/270074)
5. **Important!** Change your system time, back to the year 2011. Otherwise it'll fail (probably because the installer file is from 2011 and is only valid for a year or something like that)!
6. Go to the [ICQ for Linux page](http://www.icq.com/download/linux/en)
7. Click on `Download ICQ`
8. Click on `Open`
9. Install ICQ
10. Don't forget to change your system time back!

Please note that this all indicates that this application is just very old. I've tested it to be working, but I haven't tested if it's still able to connect to the ICQ servers (their protocol may have changed). Also I don't know the security risk of installing all this old software.

System requirements from their website:

```
Adobe Air 2.5
Fedora Core 13, Ubuntu 10.10, or openSUSE® 11.3
Release date: 22.5.2011
```

Comment: I will try, thanks! And yes, I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Your answer almost work, I will edit the question and you'll see what happens.

Comment: Question edited, please, take a look.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Well, another edit. I got it installed. Apparently you've to change your system time back to the year 2011 for it to install. This is probably because the installer file is from 2011 and is probably valid for only a year or so.

Comment: I always receive "bash: ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin: Permission denied" when try to install "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin". If I "sudo", I got `sudo: ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin: command not found`

Comment: Oh, you've to set the executable bit first: `sudo chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`.

Comment: Again, thanks. But again, another error: "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" (when installing)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module`.