# How can I install Adobe AIR on 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, adobe-air

[image: Screenshot of error]

I have a couple of games that need AIR and I thought I might take a look to see if there was a Linux version out there. There is, so I grabbed that off Adobe and tried to install it.

The first problem was that it wanted `libgnome-keyring`. I installed that from a old rpm and symlinked it with the specific library that it wanted. The next problem is that even though `ar` and `dpkg-deb` are installed and can be used, it still failed with the installation.

I have no clue whatsoever to do from here so I'm wondering, is it possible to install Adobe Air 2.6 on a modern Linux system?

Comment: That was asked nearly 7 years ago so i don't think this a dupe

Comment: I originally followed those instructions but that failed badly

Comment: Read the original post for details and if you more, you have to tell what details to give.

Comment: Please run this command for 32 bits sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf and for 64 bits sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386

Comment: Its still failing with the exact same message

Comment: @zwets Not a dupe

Comment: For instance, have you tried installing [the debs](https://askubuntu.com/a/898567/134479)? What went wrong when you tried?

Comment: I couldn't actually find the debs for this tho. I should read some of the answers sometimes. Thanks

Comment: Just decided to come back to say this

Comment: The .debs don't work. I still get the error message when i try to install a .air app. Also all of the answers in the other one just say to grab the debs or the .bin from adobe.I'm just going to give up with air at this point

Comment: That question does not have an answer for 18.04 - I think this is a valid question